# Better way to write this JS reduce() code?

Tags: javascript

the function below simply returns the smallest element in the given array using a reduce function. However, I quickly realized that the code below would throw a TypeError if the given array is empty:

```
function findSmallestElement(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((a,b) => a < b ? a : b); //throws TypeError if arr is an empty array 
}
```

So I handled it by throwing in a quick if statement before the reduce() method, as shown below. I'm wondering, is there a more elegant/concise way to do this, given that I must return 0 if the array is empty?

```
function findSmallestElement(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) return 0;
  return arr.reduce((a,b) => a < b ? a : b);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the conditional operator and spread into `Math.min`:

```js
const findSmallestElement = arr => arr.length === 0
  ? 0
  : Math.min(...arr);
console.log(findSmallestElement([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(findSmallestElement([]));
```

But

> given that I must return 0 if the array is empty?

I think this is a mistake, or at least *should* be considered to be a mistake. An array which is empty does really not have a minimum value. If the array is empty, you might consider returning something other than an ordinary number, something which couldn't be considered to be an ordinary minimum value. It's also unintuitive for, for example, `findSmallestElement([-1])` to return `-1`, but `findSmallestElement([])` to return 0.

You might emulate the functionality of `Math.min` instead, and return `Infinity`:

```js
const findSmallestElement = arr => Math.min(...arr);
console.log(findSmallestElement([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(findSmallestElement([]));
```

Or maybe return `null`. Returning 0 is *confusing*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `reduce` 2nd argument default value set based on array length.

```js
const smallest = (arr = []) =>
  arr.reduce(
    (small, curr) => Math.min(small, curr),
    arr.length > 0 ? Infinity : 0
  );

console.log(smallest([9, 2, 4]));
console.log(smallest());
console.log(smallest([]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const findSmallestElement = arr => arr && arr.length 
  ? arr.sort()[0] 
  : 0

console.log(findSmallestElement())
console.log(findSmallestElement([]))
console.log(findSmallestElement([4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 6]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let x = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
 return acc > curr ? curr : acc
}, arr[0])
```

what you have to do is to pass the initial value as the second param to the reduce. usually we pass 0 as the initial value, but as per your requirement, you should always pass **any of the array element**(like i did, first element is more transparent) else it'll always return 0 and it'd be wrong.